# Conditions based upon selected target

Tags: iphone

I have a multi-app project which is determined by the Target. Is it possible to have a conditional statement to determine which target is selected.

I.e I have 2 variations of a similar controller but want to display the relevant one depending on the target

Im hoping for something like the #if/#endif

Answer (score 1):

In your target's xcconfig file, assign a preprocessor macro to test against with `#if`:

GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = TARGET_MYAPP

If you're using the build pane, this is the "Preprocessor Macros" entry on the target's build pane. You should then [switch to xcconfig files](http://robnapier.net/blog/build-system-1-build-panel-360). The [Growl source code](http://growl.info/downloads_developers.php) is a good example of a complex multi-target project using xcconfig.